# Case insensitive find character in `evil` and `evil-easymotion`

Tags: evil

I wonder whether it is possible to make `f` in `evil` and/or in `evil-easymotion` case insensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting to do this for Evil's `f`.  If you inspect the command's definition you'll find that it binds `case-fold-search` to `nil` which makes Emacs treat search results case-sensitively.  What you can do here is copying its definition, renaming the command and changing the value of `case-fold-search` to `t`, then binding the renamed command to the original key:

```
(evil-define-motion my-evil-find-char (count char)
    "Move to the next COUNT'th occurrence of CHAR.
Movement is restricted to the current line unless `evil-cross-lines' is non-nil."
    :type inclusive
    (interactive "<c><C>")
    (setq count (or count 1))
    (let ((fwd (> count 0)))
      (setq evil-last-find (list #'evil-find-char char fwd))
      (when fwd (forward-char))
      (let ((case-fold-search t))
        (unless (prog1
                    (search-forward (char-to-string char)
                                    (unless evil-cross-lines
                                      (if fwd
                                          (line-end-position)
                                        (line-beginning-position)))
                                    t count)
                  (when fwd (backward-char)))
          (user-error "Can't find %c" char)))))

(with-eval-after-load 'evil
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "f") 'my-evil-find-char))
```

Exercise left to the reader: Doing the equivalent for `F` and easy-motion commands.

Comment: Thanks. I don't quite understand all of the stuff in the `evil-easymotion`, I've tried to replace the function names with `my-evil-find-char` but couldn't make it work. I guess it would take a bit of effort. BUT. I have just renamed your function to `evil-find-char`, load it after `evil` and it seems that it has over-written the original function. And it works perfectly fine with `evil-easymotion`. I suppose it's not a good idea to over-write stuff but it works fine for this purpose.